# Writing lambda expressions in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, lambda, clisp

I am currently reading ANSI Common Lisp by Paul Graham, and I have a question about writing lambda expressions.

Do we need to prefix a lambda expression with `#'`?. If I write something like this in REPL, it will work fine

```
> ((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 1)
  2
```

so will this

```
> (mapcar (lambda (x) (+ x x)) '(1 2 3 4))
  (2 4 6 8)
```

I understand that `#'` denotes a function. So my question is, is it some sort of convention or recommended practice? Can anything go wrong if I don't prefix lambdas with `#'`, is it implementation dependent?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my [older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3325572/271324).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**The LAMBDA expression**

`(lambda ...)` is considered to be a *lambda expression* only in certain places, like the `function` form or as the head of a function call. Lambda expressions are not evaluated.

```
(function              ; special operator FUNCTION
  (lambda () 'foobar)) ; <- this is a lambda expression


(                    ; a function call
 (lambda (foo) foo)  ; <- this is a lambda expression
 'bar                ; argument
)
```

But here `(lambda ...)` is a macro form and not a lambda expression:

```
(funcall             ; calling a function via funcall
 (lambda (foo) foo)  ; this is not a lambda expressions, but the macro lambda
                     ;  as all arguments to FUNCALL it will be
                     ;    macro expanded and evaluated
                     ;  it expands to (function (lambda (foo) foo))
 'bar)               ; argument
```

**The LAMBDA macro**

[LAMBDA](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_lambda.htm) is a macro. It expands `(lambda ...)` to `(function (lambda ...))`, which is the equivalent of `#'(lambda ...))`.

```
CL-USER > (macroexpand '(lambda (foo) foo))
(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (FOO) FOO))
```

The macro saves you a bit of writing/reading, that's all. In the first version of Common Lisp (CLtL1) there was no `LAMBDA` macro. It has been added later and is now a part of *ANSI Common Lisp*,

**The FUNCTION special operator**

[FUNCTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm#function) is a special operator. It expects a function name or a *lambda expression*. Thus the name or the *lambda expression* are not evaluated. In fact *lambda expressions* can't be evaluated at all. Inside `FUNCTION`, the *lambda expression* is **not** a macro form and thus will **not** be expanded again. The purpose of `FUNCTION` is to return the corresponding function object which is denoted by the name or by the *lambda expression*. It returns the function object as a value. With this special operator one can access the function object from global functions and lexical functions.

The `FUNCTION` operator is necessary in Common Lisp, because it has separate namespaces for values, functions and a few other things. It as a so-called *Lisp-2* or even *Lisp-n*, with two or more namespaces.

**Lambda expressions in function position in a function form**

`((lambda (foo) foo) 10)` is supported by built-in syntax for Common Lisp. See [Lambda Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm).

**Confusing**

This is all logical, but confusing. Don't worry you are not alone, but in practice it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't get why people explicitly write #' before a lambda expression though.

Comment: It's a matter of style. Some prefer it, some don't. I prefer it, as it allows to easily identify actual functions used as values. It also makes it easier to replace with an `flet` or `labels` function. Other than lambdas, it also makes a function's definition be looked up. This may be desirable if you don't know if an implementation coerces a [function designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_designator) upfront, e.g. `(mapcar 'frob my-list)` may lookup `frob`'s `symbol-function` as many times as the elements in `my-list`.

Comment: Doug Hoyte provides an argument for not using the #' syntax. Rainer hints at it here; the fact that ((lambda (foo) is built-in syntax, and there's a (lambda macro, means that you can do some interesting things with this duality of syntax when using read macros. Check out Hoyte's cl-ppcre read-macro extension as an example: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html#sec_4

Comment: Regarding claytonstanleys' comment: A quick warning, 'Let Over Lambda' contains some macro techniques which some find questionable in style and maintainability. I love the book and heartily recommend buying it but do be aware that there is deep magic in there and one should think very hard about the end user/coder who will be looking at your code in future.