# Lambda-returning macro in common lisp does not work

Tags: lambda, macros, common-lisp

I want to create a macro that returns a lambda, but I keep getting compile errors.
When you macroexpand regular lambdas you get the following:

```
(print (macroexpand '(LAMBDA (X) (+ 1 X))))

=> #'(LAMBDA (X) (+ 1 X))
```

Now, let's say I want to create a macro that expands to a lambda, for example:

```
(defmacro test (x) `(lambda (x) (+ 1 x)))
```

If I print the expansion of that macro I get the expected expansion:

```
(print (macroexpand '(test x)))

=> #'(LAMBDA (X) (+ 1 X))
```

Exactly the same as a regular lambda.
But when I try to use the "test" macro I still have to use "funcall" to make it work.

```
(print ((LAMBDA (X) (+ 1 X)) 1))
=> 2

(print (funcall (test x) 1))
=> 2

(print ((test x) 1))

=>  Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  ((TEST X) 1)
Compile-time error:
  illegal function call
```

How is this possible?

The `test` macro expands to a regular lambda, and my understanding is that after the expansion, lisp should not be able to know that it even came from a macro, it should be indistinguishable from a lambda.
How is common lisp able to use regular lambdas in the operator position of expressions without using "funcall" and how can I do the same?
Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213772/69545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator position of an expression is not treated as an expression, so it doesn't undergo macro expansion like the arguments do.

It works for `LAMBDA` because the syntax of the operator position specifically allows for lambda expressions there. The fact that there's a macro named `LAMBDA` is a coincidence, it's not used to implement this. It's specified in the CLHS description of [Lambda Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/03_ababd.htm):

> A lambda form is similar to a function form, except that the function name is replaced by a lambda expression.

Lambda forms are mostly a legacy feature for compatibility with earlier dialects. And the `LAMBDA` macro was a Common Lisp innovation, which was created just as a convenience so we wouldn't have to type `#'` whenever we use a lambda expression as a value. This is unrelated to the use of lambda expressions in lambda forms.