# When to use #' (function) in front of lambda expressions?

Tags: common-lisp

I understand that, because there are separate namespaces in Common Lisp for functions and variables, you can do this:

```
((lambda (x) (* 2 x)) 3)
```

and you can also do this:

```
(funcall #'(lambda (x) (* 2 x)) 3)
```

When should we use `#'` as opposed to not using it? I read in another StackOverflow question that `#'` was only kept around for historic reasons and shouldn't be used anymore. Is this true? My question is not a duplicate, I am asking about when I would use these in my code.

Comment: What Lisp are you talking about? Both forms are illegal in Common Lisp.

Comment: @RainerJoswig makes an important point, those forms are syntactically incorrect, but it's because of the lambda list `x`, not because `((lambda ...) ...)` or `(funcall #'(lambda ...) ...)` is syntactically incorrect.  You need to use `((lambda (x) (* 2 x)) 3)` and `(funcall #'(lambda (x) (* 2 x)) 3)`.

Comment: If an answer to another question said that you shouldn't use it anymore, then asking when you should use it is probably a duplicate.  Can you link to the other question for context?  That will make it clearer whether it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: Are you referring to [Why #' is used before lambda in Common Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3325499/1281433)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an issue of lisp-2 versus lisp-1.  With `lambda` expressions in a position where a function value is needed, it's simply a stylistic choice.  Some people like the visual marker of `#'` and some don't.  The [`lambda` macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_lambda.htm) already expands into the `function` form for which `#'` provides an abbreviation:

> [*Macro* **LAMBDA**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_lambda.htm)
>
> ```
>     (lambda lambda-list [[declaration* | documentation]] form*)
>  ==  (function (lambda lambda-list [[declaration* | documentation]] form*))
>  ==  #'(lambda lambda-list [[declaration* | documentation]] form*)
> ```

`#'x` is just syntactic sugar for `(function x)`, and the [`function` special operator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm#function) provides "the functional value of name in the current lexical environment."  T

> [*Special Operator* **FUNCTION**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm#function)
>
> The value of function is the functional value of name in the current
>   lexical environment.
>
> If name is a function name, the functional definition of that name is
>   that established by the innermost lexically enclosing flet, labels, or
>   macrolet form, if there is one. Otherwise the global functional
>   definition of the function name is returned.

While `(lambda ...)` is the name of a function, it's not a name that could ever be established by a `flet`, `label`, or `macrolet` form, so you're always getting "the global definition of the function name", which is just the lambda function.  Since `(lambda ...)` expands to `(function (lambda ...))`, there's no difference.  It's just a matter of style.

However, it is important to note that in the first case that you talked about,

```
((lambda (x) (* x 2)) 3)
```

you *could not* do:

```
(#'(lambda (x) (* x 2)) 3)            ; or
((function (lambda (x) (* x 2))) 3)
```

The support for `((lambda ...) ...)` is part of the language, unrelated to the fact that there's a definition of `lambda` as a macro.  It's a particular type of [compound form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#compound_form), namely a [lambda form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lambda_form), which is described in the HyperSpec:

> #### [3.1.2.1.2.4 Lambda Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm)
>
> A lambda form is similar to a function form, except that the function
>   name is replaced by a lambda expression.
>
> A lambda form is equivalent to using funcall of a lexical closure of
>   the lambda expression on the given arguments. (In practice, some
>   compilers are more likely to produce inline code for a lambda form
>   than for an arbitrary named function that has been declared inline;
>   however, such a difference is not semantic.)
>
> For further information, see [Section 3.1.3 (Lambda Expressions)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ac.htm).

Comment: (+1) I can only aspire to know as much as you, Rainer and a few others on this Lisp group know about Lisp :)

Comment: @mbratch Just give it some time, hang out around here, on comp.lang.lisp, and browse the HyperSpec.  It'll come with time. :)