# Why must I funcall a function returned from another?

Tags: common-lisp, lisp-2

Why doesn't this work?

```
( ((lambda () (lambda (x) (funcall #'1+ x)))) 2)
 ; yields Compile-time error: illegal function call
```

I ran into a situation like this and it later turned out that a `funcall` fixes it, i.e.

```
(funcall ((lambda () (lambda (x) (funcall #'1+ x)))) 2) ; => 3
```

I'm confused because it seems like the first one should work, because I actually have a function I'm calling, not just a symbol that may belong to either namespace (i.e. `(type-of ((lambda () #'1+))) ; => FUNCTION`). I thought it would be kind of like how you don't *need* to `funcall` a lambda for example, e.g.`((lambda (x) x) :HI) ; => :HI`. What am I missing?

Comment: Also have a look at [When to use #' (function) in front of lambda expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538564/when-to-use-function-in-front-of-lambda-expressions)  The question is slightly different, but much of the answer applies, and the relevant part of the hyperspec for why `((lambda (x) (+ 2 x)) 40) => 42` works is cited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of Common Lisp requires that, everytime you want to call a function through a compund form of the type:

```
(f a1 a2 ... an)
```

the first element of the list, `f`, must be a symbol denoting a function name, or a list denoting a *lambda expression*, i.e. (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lambda_expression)):

> **lambda expression** *n*. a *list* which can be used in place of a *function name* in certain contexts to denote a *function* by directly describing its behavior rather than indirectly by referring to the name of an *established function*; its name derives from the fact that its first element is the *symbol* lambda.

So, this basically means that you cannot have as first element any expression that returns a function as value. In those cases, you must use `funcall`.

So, in your second example, the first argument of the `funcall` is `((lambda () (lambda (x) (funcall #'1+ x))))`, which is a correct coumpound form, in which the first element of the list is the lambda expression `(lambda () (lambda (x) (funcall #'1+ x)))` (applied to an empty list of arguments).

In the first example, instead, you have as first element of the list an expression returning a function, so that you must use `funcall`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much. Is there another construct that's classified as a "lambda expression" other than a lambda form? I followed the manual but it's very vague from how it is in practice.

Comment: No, a lambda expression is a list starting with the symbol lambda, and with a correct syntax. There are no other kinds of lambda expressions.

Comment: @MasterMastic "**Lambda expression**" only applies to `(lambda ...)`, but the language also defines [**lambda forms**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm), which are the forms where the car is a lambda expression that you mentioned, e.g., `((lambda (x) (+ 40 x)) 2) => 42`.

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp uses the word *form* for everything which can be evaluated.
A *form* is either

- a *symbol* like `foo`
- a *compound form*, a list, see below
- or a *self-evaluating object* (like numbers, characters, arrays, strings, ...).

A *compound form* is either

- a *special form* `(<special-operator> ...)`
- a *lambda form* like `(lambda (...) ...)`
- a *macro form* `(<macroname> ...)`
- or a *function form* `(<functionname> ...)`.

Above is the set of compound forms. The ANSI Common Lisp specification provides no way to add a new type of forms or a different syntax. The interface of what forms the functions like `EVAL` or `COMPILE` accept is not extensible.

So something like

```
(((lambda (foo)
    (lambda (bar)
      (list foo bar)))
  1)
 2)
```

is not valid Common Lisp. This is not meaningful in Common Lisp:

```
( <not a lambda form,
   not a special operator,
   not a macro name
   and not a function name>
2)
```

Note that Common Lisp allows *lambda forms*, *special operators*, *macro names* and *function* names as the first element in a compound form. But it does **not** allow *variables* and it does **not** allow other *compound forms* as the first element in a compound form.

Means this is not meaningful in Common Lisp:

```
( <a function form> 2)
```

Thus `((foo 1) 2)` or `(((foo 1) 2) 3)` or `((((foo 1) 2) 3) 4)` or `(((((foo 1) 2) 3) 4) 5)` is not legal in Common Lisp. You get the idea. To call function objects returned from function calls, we have to use `(funcall (foo ...) ...)`. This makes calling returned function objects more obvious than just `((foo ...) ...)`.

Let's praise the designers of Common Lisp for this feature. Otherwise I might have to look at possibly meaningful code beginning with

```
(((((((((((( .....
```

and it would be very hard to figure out what it does. Basically that would be write-only code.

**Your question**:

*Why must I funcall a function returned from another?*

The short answer: because the syntax does not allow other ways, in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this [article](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html) and then modified my code below：

```
(defparameter *my-fun* 1)

(defun my-func (v0)   
  (setf (symbol-function '*my-fun*)
    (lambda (v1)
      (+ v0 v1)))   
   '*my-fun*)
```

And call it in this way `((my-func 2) 3)`,but it also report "illegal function call". I think my code is keeping with lambda calculus,but where is wrong.

In my opinion, (my-func 2) returns symbol *my_fun*, and the function cell of *my-fun* points to a function object, so ((my-func 2) 3) => (*my-fun* 3) => ((lambda (v1) (+ 2 v1)) 3) => (+ 2 3) => 5

Answer (score 0):

This works: First your identical definitions:

```
(defparameter *my-fun* 1)

(defun my-func (v0)   
  (setf (symbol-function '*my-fun*)
    (lambda (v1)
      (+ v0 v1)))   
   '*my-fun*)
```

However, invoke using **funcall**:

```
(funcall (my-func 2) 3)
```