# Lisp, do something for every element in a list

Tags: foreach, lisp

How do I perform a function on every element in a list? For example say I have a list:

```
(1 x q)
```

and I was to use `my-function` on `1`, `x`, `q`. Is there a predefined function for this? Similarly to `foreach` in a "higher" level language? Or do I have to manually step through it using `car` and `cdr`?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the tool for learning the basics of a programming language. It is expected that you put yourself some effort into solving a problem.
For learning the basics of Lisp see this book with a PDF version for download: Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/
Especially see chapter 7.

Comment: See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html#mapping, http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html#looping and http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html.

Comment: I looked for loops to when trying to learn Lisp. Use [MAPCAR](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) or loop eg. `(loop :for element :in '(1 x q) :collect (list element))`. I recommend buying [Land of Lisp](http://www.landoflisp.com/)

Comment: `...in a "higher" level language?` - hey, I wouldn't say that Lisp is "lower" level programming language compared with any of them.

Comment: "higher level"? Lisp exists on all levels, if the programmer wants; it can soar on levels of which lesser languages don't even dare to dream.

Comment: if you heard about "manually step[ping] through it using car and cdr", why don't you write some code along those lines? don't be afraid of reinventing the wheel, that's how you learn the language. After you become more comfortable with the language, you will start using library functions more and more.

Comment: Given the plethora of options, this is a valid question for several levels of lisp knowledge or skill.  Try assuming that the asker IS being very specific: they don't need the return value.  That's how my google-fu led me to this specific question.  I'm thinking that MAP is what I need, as opposed to MAPCAR, but I'm not sure yet...

Comment: With respect, hard disagree on Mr. Joswig's description of stackoverflow's purpose (though in agreement with his book recommendation). It is not a particularly valuable use of one's time to memorize the entire suite of language quirks when one really only needs to be reminded how one language expresses the concept of "for-each"---a concept so common, in fact, I was surprised the answer wasn't actually "Common Lisp has a built-in 'for-each'. But no; LISP is so ancient it has its own outlier names for the common concept, and finding those outlier names is exactly what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to construct a fresh list of results of `my-function`, use [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```
(mapcar #'my-function my-list)
```

If you do not want the results, use [`mapc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) or [`dolist`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm) or [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm).

See also

1. [What's the best way to learn LISP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398579/850781)
2. [The #' in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14021965/850781)
3. [Why #' is used before lambda in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3325499/850781)

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is.

Look a the [hyperspec symbol index](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/X_Symbol.htm) and read about the following:

- `map`, `map-into`
- `mapcar`, `mapcan`, `mapcon`, `mapc`, `mapl`, `maplist`
- `dolist`
- `loop`: `(loop :for element :in list #|...|#)`

If you need the results as another list of the same length: `map`, `map-into`, `mapcar`, `loop`.
If you want to do it by side effects: `dolist`, `loop`.

Comment: `mapc` and `mapl` are also for side-effect-only operations, like `dolist`.