# Common Lisp a Lisp-n?

Tags: namespaces, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-2

I'm aware that Common Lisp has different binding environments for functions and variables, but I believe that it also has another binding environment for tagbody labels. Are there even more binding environments than this?  If so, then is it fair to categorize Common Lisp as a Lisp-2?

These question are not meant as pedantry or bike-shedding, I only want to gain a better understanding of Common Lisp and hopefully get some pointers into where to dig deeper into its spec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm aware that Common Lisp has different binding environments for
>   functions and variables,

That would be *namespaces*, according to the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_n.htm#namespace):

> namespace n. 1. bindings whose denotations are restricted to a
>   particular kind. `The bindings of names to tags is the tag
>   namespace.'' 2. any mapping whose domain is a set of names.`A
>   package defines a namespace.''

(Point 1.)

> but I believe that it also has another binding environment for tagbody
>   labels. Are there even more binding environments than this?

Yes, there are more namespaces. I even remember a little snippet exposing most of them, but unfortunately, I can't find it anymore¹. It at least exposed *variable*, *function*, *tag*, and *block* namespaces, but maybe also *types* and *declarations* were included. There is also [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021811/271324) that lists these namespaces.

> If so, then is it fair to categorize Common Lisp as a Lisp-2?

In the comments to the above linked answer, Rainer Joswig agrees that the "general debate is about Lisp-1 against Lisp-n".

The "2" might be due to the relative importance of the distinction between value and function slots, or because the objects of the other namespaces aren't first-class objects. For example in the [Gabriel/Pitman paper](http://www.dreamsongs.com/Separation.html) referenced in the other answer:

> There is really a larger number of namespaces than just the two that
>   are discussed here. As we noted earlier, other namespaces include at
>   least those of blocks and tags; type names and declaration names are
>   often considered namespaces. Thus, the names Lisp1 and Lisp2, which we
>   have been using are misleading. The names Lisp5 and Lisp6 might be
>   more appropriate.

and:

> In this paper, there are two namespaces of concern, which we
>   shall term the "value namespace" and the "function namespace." Other
>   namespaces include tag names (used by TAGBODY and GO) and block names
>   (used by BLOCK and RETURN-FROM), but the objects in the location parts
>   of their bindings are not first-class Lisp objects.

---

¹) [PAIP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558601910), p. 837:

```
(defun f (f)
  (block f
    (tagbody
     f (catch 'f
         (if (typep f 'f)
             (throw 'f (go f)))
         (funcall #'f (get (symbol-value 'f) 'f))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

In PAIP, Peter Norvig says "Common Lisp has at least seven name spaces" (p. 836).

The seven he lists are:

1. functions and macros
2. variables
3. special variables
4. data types
5. label for go statements within a tagbody
6. a block name for return-from statements within a block
7. symbols inside a quoted expression

Peter Seibel makes a great point in his comp.lang.lisp post about "compiler" versus "library" namespaces.  I think all of Norvig's seven namespaces are "compiler" namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

See for example this old discussion post from comp.lang.lisp:

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Lisp/comp.lang.lisp/2004-04/0737.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes - http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/t_symbol.htm#symbol specifies a separate value cell and function cell, consonant with a lisp-2.

There is also a property list, but as there is no context in which a symbol "naturally" refers to its property list, it is not usual to describe CL as a lisp-3 (in fact, I am not aware of any language usually so designated).