# Function name and dynamic binding in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, eval, common-lisp, dynamic-binding

I'm reading Peter Norvig's *Paradigms of AI*. In chapter 6.2, the author uses code like below (*not the original code, I picked out the troubling part*):

**Code Snippet:**

```
(progv '(op arg) '(1+ 1)
(eval '(op arg)))
```

As the author's original intent, this code *should return **2***, but in `sbcl 1.1.1`, the interpreter is apparently not looking up **op** in the environment, throwing out `op: undefined function`.

Is this implementation specific? Since the code must have been tested on some other lisp.

p.s [Original code](http://www.norvig.com/paip/patmatch.lisp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean

```
(progv '(op arg) '(1+ 1)
  (eval '(funcall op arg)))
```

#### Edit(2013-08-21):

PAIP was written in pre-ANSI-Common-Lisp era, so it's possible the code
there contains a few noncompliances wrt the standard.  We can make
the examples work with the following revision:

```
(defun match-if (pattern input bindings)
  "Test an arbitrary expression involving variables.
  The pattern looks like ((?if code) . rest)."
  (and (eval (reduce (lambda (code binding)
                       (destructuring-bind (var . val) binding
                         (subst val var code)))
                     bindings :initial-value (second (first pattern))))
       (pat-match (rest pattern) input bindings)))

;; CL-USER> (pat-match '(?x ?op ?y is ?z (?if (eql (?op ?x ?y) ?z))) '(3 + 4 is 7))
;; ((?Z . 7) (?Y . 4) (?OP . +) (?X . 3) (T . T))
;; CL-USER> (pat-match '(?x ?op ?y (?if (?op ?x ?y))) '(3 > 4))
;; NIL
```

Comment: I think I mean it the other way, please look at Norvig's [original text](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=QzGuHnDhvZIC&lpg=PA186&vq=here%20are%20two%20examples%20using%20%3Fif&pg=PA186#v=snippet&q=here%20are%20two%20examples%20using%20?if&f=false).

Comment: Following works without changing PAIP code: (pat-match '(?x ?op ?y is ?z (?if (eql (funcall ?op ?x ?y) ?z))) '(3 + 4 is 7))

Comment: @ahsankhan - agreed, much the easiest way.

Comment: The alternative would be to write a new version of 'eval' for the pattern-matcher that either tests for bindings that are functions, or spots binding variables in the car position of an evaluated cons pair and adds funcall to the expression - either way is a bit messy. Using 'subst' as suggested by huaiyuan is a nice quick fix, but potentially changes the evaluation value, although it doesn't seem to matter for any of the uses in the book. Personally, coming from Scheme to Common Lisp, I find the function-namespace thing irritating.

Comment: @Jiaji, Norvig's code doesn't work in my version SBCL because (eval '(op arg)) is not correct code in ANSI-Common Lisp when op is bound to a function, but may have been OK in whichever version of Common Lisp he was using (perhaps it had a smarter progv implementation?). (progv '(op arg) '(1+ 1) (eval '(funcall op arg))) is necessary. How to get the pattern matcher to do the right thing is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Elements in first positions are not looked up as values, but as functions and there is no concept of dynamic binding in the function namespace.

I'd say after a quick look that the original code was designed to evaluate in a context like

```
 (progv '(x y) '(12 34)
   (eval '(> (+ x y) 99)))
```

i.e. evaluating a formula providing substitution for variables, not for function names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the author seemed to use it my way [in his book?](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=QzGuHnDhvZIC&lpg=PA186&vq=here%20are%20two%20examples%20using%20%3Fif&pg=PA186#v=snippet&q=here%20are%20two%20examples%20using%20?if&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers so far are right, in that the actual form being evaluated is not the variables being bound by `progv` (simply `(op arg)`), but none have mentioned what *is* being evaluated.  In fact, the comments in the code you linked to provide a (very) short explanation (this is the only code in that file that uses `progv`):

```
(defun match-if (pattern input bindings)
  "Test an arbitrary expression involving variables.
  The pattern looks like ((?if code) . rest)."
  ;; *** fix, rjf 10/1/92 (used to eval binding values)
  (and (progv (mapcar #'car bindings)
              (mapcar #'cdr bindings)
          (eval (second (first pattern))))
       (pat-match (rest pattern) input bindings)))
```

The idea is that a call to `match-if` gets called like

```
(match-if '((?if code) . rest) input ((v1 val1) (v2 val2) ...))
```

and `eval` is called with `(second (first pattern))`, which the value of `code`. However, `eval` is called within the `progv` that binds `v1`, `v2`, &c., to the corresponding `val1`, `val2`, &c., so that if any of those variables appear free in `code`, then they are bound when `code` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The problem that I see here is that, by the code we can't tell if the value is to be saved as the variable's `symbol-value` or `symbol-function`. Thus when you put a `+` as a value to some corresponding variable, say `v`, then it'll always be saved as the `symbol-value` of `var`, not it's `symbol-function`.
Therefore when you'll try to use it as, say `(v 1 2)` , it won't work. Because there is no function named `v` in the *functions' namespace*(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020968/separate-namespaces-for-functions-and-variables-in-common-lisp-versus-scheme)).

### So, what to do?

A probable solution can be explicit checking for the value that is to be bound to a variable. If the value is a function, then it should be bound to the variable's  function value. This checking can be done via `fboundp`.

So, we can  make a macro `functioner`  and a modified version of `match-if`. `functioner` checks if the value is a function, and sets it aptly. `match-if` does the dynamic local bindings, and allows other code in the scope of the bound variables.

```
(defmacro functioner (var val)
  `(if (and (symbolp ',val)
            (fboundp ',val))
       (setf (symbol-function ',var) #',val)
       (setf ,var ,val)))


(defun match-if (pattern input bindings)
  (eval `(and (let ,(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (list (car x))) bindings)
                (declare (special ,@ (mapcar #'car bindings)))
                (loop for i in ',bindings
                      do (eval `(functioner ,(first i) ,(rest i))))
                (eval (second (first ',pattern))))
              (pat-match (rest ',pattern) ',input ',bindings))))
```