# Neither a function nor a macro would do

Tags: common-lisp, eval, backquote

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331753/function-name-and-dynamic-binding-in-common-lisp) question. Here the basic problem is the code:

```
(progv '(op arg) '(1+ 1)
 (eval '(op arg)))
```

The problem here is that `progv` binds the *value* to the *variable* as variable's `symbol-value` not `symbol-function`. But, that's obvious because we didn't explicitly suggest which values are functions.

---

### The Plan

So, in order to solve this problem, I thought of manually dynamically binding the variables, to their values based on the type of values. If the values are `fboundp` then they should be bound to the `symbol-function` of the variable. A restriction, is that `match-if` can't be a `macro`. It has to be a `function`, because it is called by a `funcall`.

**Macro : `functioner`**:

```
(defmacro functioner (var val)
  `(if (and (symbolp ',val)
            (fboundp ',val))
       (setf (symbol-function ',var) #',val)
       (setf ,var ,val)))
```

**Function: `match-if`**:

```
(defun match-if (pattern input bindings)
  (eval `(and (let ,(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (list (car x))) bindings)
                (declare (special ,@ (mapcar #'car bindings)))
                (loop for i in ',bindings
                      do (eval `(functioner ,(first i) ,(rest i))))
                (eval (second (first ,pattern))))
              (pat-match (rest ,pattern) ,input ,bindings))))
```

Here, the `let` part declares all the variables lexically (supposedly). Then `declare` declares them `special`. Then `functioner` binds the variables and their values aptly. Then the code in the pattern is evaluated. If the code part is true, then only the pattern-matcher function `pat-match` is invoked.

---

### The Problem

The problem is that in the function, all it's arguments are evaluated. Thus `bindings` in the `let` and `declare` parts will be replaced by something like :
`((v1 . val1)(v2 . val2)(v3 . val3))`
not
`'((v1 . val1)(v2 . val2)(v3 . val3))`
So, it's treated as code, not a list.
So, I'm stuck here. And macros won't help me on this one.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you are looking for, but [`PROGV`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm) is a special operator; it is granted the ability to modify the dynamic bindings of variables at runtime; AFAIK, you can't simply hack it to operate on "dynamic function bindings".
The point of `progv` is to use list of symbols and values that are evaluated, meaning that you can generate symbols at runtime and bind them dynamically to the corresponding values.

You might be able to find a solution with `eval` but note that if you macroexpand into `(eval ...)`, then you loose the surrounding lexical context, which is generally not what you want ("eval" operates on the null lexical environment). I speculate that you could also have a custom code walker which works on top-level forms but reorganizes them, when it finds your special operator, to bring the context back in, producing something like `(eval '(let (...) ...))`.

Comment: http://christophe.rhodes.io/notes/blog/posts/2014/naive_vs_proper_code-walking/ is a good start

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691747/5345646) version of `match-if` seems to work. All I had to do was add a quote before `,pattern` ,`,input` and `,bindings`.